# Is my proof for $Y_n \overset{\text{$\Bbb P$}}\longrightarrow Y$ correct ? Expected Value and Variance are given

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

*Let $Y$ be a real random variable and $Y_n:=Y+X_n$, with $(X_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ a sequence of real random variables with
$$\Bbb E[X_n]=\frac{1}{n}, Var[X_n]=\frac{\sigma^2}{n} $$

with $\sigma>0.$*

*Proof: $ Y_n \overset{\text{$\Bbb P$}}\longrightarrow Y$*

Now this is my attempt, I look for advice, for corrections, etc. thanks in advance:

Let $\epsilon >0$. Than
$$\begin{align}\Bbb P(|Y_n-Y|\geq \epsilon)&=\Bbb P(|Y_n-(Y_n-X_n)|\geq \epsilon)\\
&=\Bbb P(|X_n|\geq \epsilon)\\
&=\Bbb P(|X_n-0|\geq \epsilon)\\
&=1-\Bbb P(X_n\in (0,\epsilon))\\
\end{align}$$
Assume that $\sigma<\infty$, than Chebychev gives us
$$\Bbb P(|X_n-\frac{1}{n}|\geq \epsilon)\leq\frac{Var(X_n)}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n\epsilon^2} \overset{\text{$n \to \infty$}}\longrightarrow 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing some nuances. I would argue that,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\lvert X_n\rvert \geq \epsilon) &= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\lvert X_n\rvert - \tfrac{1}{n} + \tfrac{1}{n} \geq \epsilon),\\
&\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}(\lvert X_n - \tfrac{1}{n}\rvert \geq \epsilon - \tfrac{1}{n}),\\
&\stackrel{cc}{\leq} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{n\left(\epsilon - \tfrac{1}{n}\right)^2}\right) = 0.
\end{align*}

Since you already showed that $\mathbb{P}(\lvert Y_n - Y\rvert \geq \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\lvert X_n\rvert \geq \epsilon)$, we have by definition convergence in probability.

Also Your last line of the first block, i.e. $1-\mathbb{P}(X_n \in (0,\epsilon))$ is, I believe, not necessarily correct. Since, it is not stated that $X_n \geq 0$.